# Necessary to use Seed method to add data to mapping table?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to learn more about creating tables for database with Entity Framework and Code First. Below I have a short example from the Seed method in the Migrations/Configuration.cs file.

These two tables has a Many-To-Many relation and Visual Studio creates a new table called `ResourceProject` but this table is empty and I wonder if I have to add data like the ID to this table in the Seed like the other tables? I guess the point with a mapping table like `ResourceProject` is to use it, and not `Resource` and `Project` table when read and write to the database!?

The `ResourceProject` table just contain the ID of `Resource` and `Project`

```
            // Add Projects
        context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name,
            new Project()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Project 1",
                CompanyID = 3
            });

        // Add Resources
        context.Resources.AddOrUpdate(x => x.FirstName,
            new Resource()
            {
                ID = 1,
                FirstName = "Linda",
                LastName = "West",
                EmployeeNumber = 1,
                email = "linda.west@mail.com"
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a Resources collection on your Project entity and/or a Projects collection on your Resource entity. E.g:

```
public class Project
{
   // Other properties

   public ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
   // Other properties

   public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

To seed data in the ResourceProject table you would need to add an item to one of the above collection properties:

```
var project = new Project();
project.Resources.Add(new Resource());

// OR 

var resource = new Resource();
resource.Projects.Add(new Project());
```

The other possibility is that you've got an explicit ResourceProject entity. In which case the collection property would be the same on both the Resource and Project entities:

```
public ICollection<ResourceProject> { get; set; }
```

The same applies - you'd need to explicitly add an item to the collection to seed the data.

**EDIT **

Based on the comment you could seed the entity like this if you want a "shorthand" version:

```
// TODO: set all required properties (EmployeeNumber etc)
var lindaResource = new Resource { FirstName = "Linda", LastName = "West" };
var joeResource = new Resource { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "East" };    

context.resource.AddOrUpdate(x => x.FirstName, 
    lindaResource, 
    joeResource);

context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name,
    new Project()
    {
       ID = 1,
       Name = "Project 1",
       CompanyID = 3,
       Resources = new List<Resource> { lindaResource }
    },
    new Project()
    {
       ID = 2,
       Name = "Project 2",
       CompanyID = 3,
       Resources = new List<Resource> { lindaResource, joeResource }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I have Resources collection in Project entity and a Projects collection in Resource entity.

Comment: Just wonder, the code for my seed above is just a short version. In my project I have 3 rows for each table. Does this mean that I have to add 3 items like your code? But what am I adding to the tables with your code? What will happen with the mapping table?

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comment. I suspect the resources could get duplicated though when the seed method runs for a second time with the shorthand approach so you'd need to double check that yourself.

Comment: OK, but what if I will have different project and not set all Resources to Project 1? If I understand your code right, your shorthand will add Project 1 to both Resources Linda and Joe?

Comment: I've revised the answer again - this should allow you to reuse the resources across multiple projects without the duplication issue when re-running the seed method.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I get a error when I delete the DB and update the database in Package Manager Console. This is the error message: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'EmployeeGuide.Models.Activity_Project' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key. Do I need to add ID in your code?

Comment: Sorry I think that was due to an mistake with the context.Projects.AddOrUpdate line in my example, I've updated the example. I've also only provided property values for firstname and lastname in the example however you should set any other properties you require.

Comment: I tested to run my application without the seed and used the default Create Views to add data to the tables, but no data was added to the mapping table ResourceProject! Shouldn't some IDs be added automatically ? :(

Comment: Normally the IDs would be automatically generated for you, yes. One more thing to check is that EF has established the relationship between the entities correctly. I'm assuming it has since the ResourceProject table exists, however you may need to override the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext and explicitly define the relationship between Resource and Project.